# Can not "ldap_bind_s" to AD in C++ (0x31 error code)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to connect to AD in Windows Server 2008 according to [these instructions from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367016(v=vs.85).aspx). Until calling `ldap_bind_s` all is ok, but then I got error with 0x31 code([The supplied credential is invalid](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/218185)).

Username and password are correct, I've checked for several times.

Using C++ MSVS 2015. Here is my code sample.

```
PWSTR host_name = L"ad.server.ip.address";

LDAP* pLdapConnection = NULL;
pLdapConnection = ldap_init(host_name, LDAP_PORT);

if (pLdapConnection == NULL)
{
    printf("ldap_init failed with 0x%x.\n", LdapGetLastError());
    ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);
    return -1;
}
else
    printf("ldap_init succeeded \n");

ULONG version = LDAP_VERSION3;
ULONG lRtn = 0;

lRtn = ldap_set_option(
    pLdapConnection,          
    LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 
    (void*)&version);         

if (lRtn == LDAP_SUCCESS)
    printf("ldap version set to 3.0 \n");
else
{
    printf("SetOption Error:%0lX\n", lRtn);
    ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);
    return hr;
}

lRtn = ldap_connect(pLdapConnection, NULL);

if (lRtn == LDAP_SUCCESS)
    printf("ldap_connect succeeded \n");
else
{
    printf("ldap_connect failed with 0x%lx.\n", lRtn);
    ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);
    return -1;
}

PWSTR pMyDN = L"DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=name";
SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY secIdent;

//adm@ad.domain.name
unsigned short login[18] = { 'a', 'd', 'm', '@', 'a', 'd', '.', 'd', 'o', 'm', 'a', 'i', 'n', '.', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e' }; //18
secIdent.User = login;
secIdent.UserLength = 18;

//mypassword
unsigned short password[10] = { 'm', 'y', 'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd' }; //10
secIdent.Password = password;
secIdent.PasswordLength = 10;

//ad.domain.name
unsigned short domain[14] = { 'a', 'd', '.', 'd', 'o', 'm', 'a', 'i', 'n', '.', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e' }; //14
secIdent.Domain = dmn;
secIdent.DomainLength = 14;
secIdent.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_ANSI;

lRtn = ldap_bind_s(
    pLdapConnection,      // Session Handle
    pMyDN,                // Domain DN
    (PWCHAR)&secIdent,     // Credential structure
    LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE); // Auth mode
if (lRtn == LDAP_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("ldap_bind_s succeeded \n");
    secIdent.Password = NULL; // Remove password pointer
    pPassword = NULL;         // Remove password pointer
}
else
{
    printf("ldap_bind_s failed with 0x%lx.\n", lRtn);
    ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);
    return -1;
}
```

Console output:

```
ldap_init succeeded
ldap version set to 3.0
ldap_connect succeeded
ldap_bind_s failed with 0x31.
Cannot execute query. Cannot bind to LDAP
```

It seems to me that the error can be occured by encoding or domain name. But according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2712563/4985081), domain field in `SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY`structure is ignored. Also I tried to set `secIdent.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;` without any result.

---

### UPD.

Below is PHP code snippet that performs successful connection to same AD Server

```
$this->c = ldap_connect("ad.server.ip.address");
ldap_set_option($this->c, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
$r = ldap_bind($this->c,'adm@ad.domain.name','mypassword');
```

Comment: Have you tried using plain login without the domain ("adm")?

Comment: I've tried just now. Having the same result - 0x31 error :(

Comment: Still, I think you should use "adm" because you already pass the domain as a separate field.

Comment: Besides, the specification of ldap_bind_s() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366156(v=vs.85).aspx says that credentials (secIdent in your case) should be "Pointer to a null-terminated string that contains the credentials with which to authenticate. Arbitrary credentials can be passed using this parameter. The format and content of the credentials depends on the setting of the method parameter. For more information, see Remarks." which is not true in your case. Have you tried to use C-strings instead of unsigned short arrays or adding 0 to the end of each array?

Comment: Yes, I tried.
Just found a solution. I needed to specify another method - `LDAP_AUTH_SIMPLE` instead of `LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE`. Another way is simply using `ldap_simple_bind_s` 
@ElenaOblomova thank you for help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just **found a solution** after watching [this example](http://fm4dd.com/programming/c-code/ad_ldaptest_c.htm)

I should use `LDAP_AUTH_SIMPLE` authentication method instead of `LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE` in `ldap_bind_s()` or simply use `ldap_simple_bind_s()`.

Working code snippet

```
PWSTR host_name = L"ad.server.ip.address";

LDAP* pLdapConnection = NULL;
pLdapConnection = ldap_init(host_name, LDAP_PORT);
if (pLdapConnection == NULL)
{
    printf("ldap_init failed with 0x%x.\n", LdapGetLastError());
    ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);
    return -1;
}
else
    printf("ldap_init succeeded \n");

ULONG version = LDAP_VERSION3;
ULONG lRtn = 0;

lRtn = ldap_set_option(
    pLdapConnection,           // Session handle
    LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, // Option
    (void*)&version);         // Option value

if (lRtn == LDAP_SUCCESS)
    printf("ldap version set to 3.0 \n");
else
{
    printf("SetOption Error:%0lX\n", lRtn);
    ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);
    return 0;
}


lRtn = ldap_connect(pLdapConnection, NULL);

if (lRtn == LDAP_SUCCESS)
    printf("ldap_connect succeeded \n");
else
{
    printf("ldap_connect failed with 0x%lx.\n", lRtn);
    ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);
    return -1;
}


PWCHAR user_name = L"adm@ad.domain.name";
PWCHAR password = L"mypassword";

lRtn = ldap_simple_bind_s(pLdapConnection, user_name, password);
if (lRtn == LDAP_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("ldap_simple_bind_s succeeded \n");
}
else
{
    printf("ldap_simple_bind_s failed with 0x%lx.\n", lRtn);
    ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sspi/ns-sspi-sec_winnt_auth_identity_a)
In the link mentioned above using LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE you only need to pass the third parameter is enough.
My program works normally
Below is a snippet:

```
std::wstring username = L"Your user name ";
std::wstring password = L"Your password";
std::wstring domain = L"Your domain";

secIdentity.User = (unsigned short*) username.c_str(); // Replace with the username
secIdentity.UserLength = username.length();
secIdentity.Password = (unsigned short*) password.c_str(); // Replace with the username
secIdentity.PasswordLength = password.length();
secIdentity.Domain = (unsigned short*) domain.c_str(); // Replace with the domain
secIdentity.DomainLength = domain.length();
secIdentity.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;

//ldapResult = ldap_simple_bind_sW(ldapConnection, (PWCHAR)username.c_str(), (PWCHAR)password.c_str()); // --> work as expected

ldapResult = ldap_bind_sW(ldapConnection, NULL, (PWCHAR)&secIdentity, LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE);
```