# User Authentication using LDAP with Windows Active Directory (Windows Server 2016)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, active-directory, ldap

Platform : Windows 10 x64
Development Environment : MSVC 2017

Active Directory Platform : Windows Server 2016 (Evaluation)

I am trying to authenticate windows users located on remote server maintained using Windows Active Directory. My service running on local PC is giving **Invalid Credentials** error message (even after passing proper authenticated user name, password and domain).

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winldap.h>
#include <plog/Log.h>
#include <string>

#ifdef UNICODE
typedef std::wstring        string_type;
#define CONSOLE_OUT         std::wcout
#define CONSOLE_IN          std::wcin
#define CONSOLE_ERR         std::wcerr
#else
typedef std::string         string_type;
#define CONSOLE_OUT         std::cout
#define CONSOLE_IN          std::cin
#define CONSOLE_ERR         std::cerr
#endif

int main()
{
    SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY sec;
    string_type hostName = TEXT("192.168.1.49");
    string_type domain = TEXT("WIN-49MT1TDDGOC.darksorrow.com");
    string_type userName = TEXT("darksorrow\\ds");
    string_type password = TEXT("darksorrow@1234567890");
    PLDAP ld = nullptr;
    int ldapReturnCode;
    CONSOLE_OUT << TEXT("Hello World!\n");
    plog::init(plog::error, "error.dat", 1048576, 3); //1 M.B.
    ld = ldap_init(const_cast<PWSTR>(hostName.c_str()), LDAP_PORT);

    if (ld == nullptr)
    {
        LOG_ERROR << ldap_err2string(LdapGetLastError());
        CONSOLE_OUT << ldap_err2string(LdapGetLastError());
    }
    const int version = LDAP_VERSION3;
    ldapReturnCode = ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, std::addressof(version));
    if (ldapReturnCode not_eq LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
        LOG_ERROR << ldap_err2string(ldapReturnCode);
        CONSOLE_OUT << ldap_err2string(ldapReturnCode);
    }
    ldapReturnCode = ldap_connect(ld, NULL);
    if (ldapReturnCode not_eq LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
        LOG_ERROR << ldap_err2string(ldapReturnCode);
        CONSOLE_OUT << ldap_err2string(ldapReturnCode);
    }
    PWSTR   dn = nullptr;

    sec.Domain          = (unsigned short *) domain.data();
    sec.DomainLength    = domain.length();
    sec.User            = (unsigned short *) userName.data();
    sec.UserLength      = userName.length();
    sec.Password        = (unsigned short *) password.data();
    sec.PasswordLength  = password.length();
    sec.Flags           = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;

    CONSOLE_OUT << domain << std::endl;
    CONSOLE_OUT << userName << std::endl;
    CONSOLE_OUT << password << std::endl;

    ldapReturnCode = ldap_bind_s(ld, dn, (PWCHAR)std::addressof(sec), LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE);
    if (ldapReturnCode not_eq LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
        LOG_ERROR << ldap_err2string(ldapReturnCode);
        CONSOLE_OUT << ldap_err2string(ldapReturnCode);
    }
    else
        CONSOLE_OUT << "Authentication Success\n";
    ldap_unbind(ld);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Where am  I going wrong?

Comment: *"Where am I going wrong?"*: you are tagging this as C and C++ ;)

Comment: There's a solution here where it worked by just switching to `LDAP_AUTH_SIMPLE`:https://stackoverflow.com/a/38054608/1202807

Comment: Also, if your goal is only to authenticate the user (and not run other LDAP queries) then you could just use `LogonUserA`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera

Comment: @GabrielLuci, The problem I faced with LogonUserA is that the Active Directory Server where all uses information is available can only be accessed on network. I am not allowed to run my program on the server and as per my understanding LogonUserA only authenticates local users. If my understanding is flawed kindly enlighten me.

Comment: @GabrielLuci, After switching ldap_bind_s to LDAP_AUTH_SIMPLE, the ldap_bind_s returns success even if invalid domain name or credentials are passed.

Comment: LogonUserA takes a domain parameter, so yes, it can authenticate domain users as long as the computer you run it on is joined to a domain trusted by the domain of the user. If you're running it from a computer not joined to a domain, then yes, you'll need to use LDAP.

Comment: @GabrielLuci, the server on which Users are created & maintained and the PC on which my application is running and situated in 2 different cities. I will inquire the client's IT department of both PC are on same domain.

Comment: @GabrielLuci, any suggestions regarding ldap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to give this a try myself. Turns out the solution is simple. Your username should not contain the domain name. So change this:

```
string_type userName = TEXT("darksorrow\\ds");
```

to this:

```
string_type userName = TEXT("ds");
```

You are already specifying the domain as a separate parameter, so it's not needed as part of the username.

You should be able to still use `LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE`.

Comment: I tried with only user name. When I use LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE I get Invalid Credential Error Message (0x31) and when I use LDAP_AUTH_SIMPLE even incorrect login credential return SUCCESS message. I tried all permutation combination with domain and user name but to no avail. I even set up new server. Is their some setting I am missing. Just to be clear my Active Directory is located on : Windows Server 2016 (Evaluation) and I am running my program on Windows 10 x64 (Home/Professional) Development Environment : MSVC 2017 Community Edition

Comment: Did you try using your domain name for `hostName` instead of the IP address? You shouldn't need to specify the IP.

Comment: no haven't tried that yet. Just one question if I pass domain name in place of IP address in host name, them how will the server address be resolved?

Comment: By DNS. If you lookup the domain name (i.e. "domain.com") in DNS, it returns the IPs of all the domain controllers.

Comment: Kindly correct me if I am wrong, to test using domain name for hostName instead of the IP address I would require an Active Directory server that is live (online) on internet. I won't be able to test it on locally deployed Active Directory server (we have 3 deployed server (on 3 separate virtual machines) of purpose of development and testing).

Comment: Not necessarily on the internet, but resolvable in your DNS. If it can't, then you can try adding the domain name/IP address to your hosts file.

Comment: Will try it out.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Thank You for your guidance.